# MAX(date), GROUPBY, with WHERE

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 columns,

```
Firm_Name
Firm_Status
Firm_Date
```

Table Name: Test

I'm not sure why this doens't seem to work,

```
Select Firm_Name, Firm_Status, Max(Firm_Date)
From Test
WHERE
Firm_Status = 'Incorporated'
GROUP BY Firm_Name, Firm_Status
```

Essentially, I want the last date in the table, along with the name and status.

I'm looking for Max date in each row. There are duplicate Firm Names. If two rows are the same firms, and each have a different date, I want the max date along with the rest of the info of that firm in that row.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "*doesn't seem to work*?"  What do you mean by the "*last*" date in the table?  Are you only looking for one single record?  What is your DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)?  Can you provide some sample data and a desired result?

Comment: See here for many examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Comment: Ah sorry, No I'm looking for Max date in each row. There are duplicate Firm Names. If two rows are the same firms, and each have a different date, I want the max date along with the rest of the info of that firm in that row.

Comment: Your query is correct according to me, add expected result and actual result so it will be easy to identify where is problem is.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is either. For some of the results, I still get duplicate Firm_Name, and I get two different dates. It's not selecting the max date. I'm not joining any other tables, the query and table is all I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, very portable way:

```
Select Firm_Name, Firm_Status, Firm_Date
From Test
WHERE Firm_Status = 'Incorporated'
  and Firm_Date = (select Max(Firm_Date) from test
                   WHERE Firm_Status = 'Incorporated')
```

Comment: Sorry I should've explained what I was looking for. I've added an edit to my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
  SELECT Firm_Name, Firm_Status, Firm_Date
    FROM Test
    WHERE Firm_Date = (SELECT MAX(Firm_Date) FROM Test WHERE Firm_Status = 'Incorporated')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last date in the table, then the simplest method is `fetch first 1 row only` and `order by`:

```
Select Firm_Name, Firm_Status, Firm_Date
From Test
where Firm_Status = 'Incorporated'
order by firm_date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

A `group by` is unnecessary, even distracting.

Note that some databases spell `fetch first 1 row only` as `limit` or `select top`.